# Django Port from Postgres to MariaDB manage.py migrate error SQL Syntax Error 1064

Tags: python, django, mariadb

I am porting my Django application from Postgres to MariaDB and receive the following error when doing the migration step:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[20] NOT NULL, `last_update` datetime(6) NOT NULL, `commited` bool NOT NULL, ...' at line 1")
```

All the standard Django tables are created and my first model table is created. But I never get beyond that step.

My models are all of the following style:

```
class Country(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,
                                help_text=_('This is the full name of the country'),
                                verbose_name=_('Country'),
                                )
        alternate_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True,
                                help_text=_('This is the alternate name - often abbreviation - of the country'),
                                verbose_name=_('Country alternate name'),
                                )
        iso_numeric = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0,null=True,
                                help_text=_('This is the ISO numeric code of the country'),
                                verbose_name=_('ISO numeric code'),
                                )
        iso_alpha = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True,
                                help_text=_('This is the ISO alpha code of the country'),
                                verbose_name=_('ISO alpha code'),
                                )
        last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                help_text=_('This is the timestamp of the last update'),
                                verbose_name=_('Timestamp last update'),
                                )
        last_update_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, editable=False,
                                help_text=_('This is the user making last update'),
                                verbose_name=_('User making last update'),
                                )
        committed = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False,
                                help_text=
                                _('This field is set to false once record is created until admin has committed it'),
                                verbose_name=_('Committed'),
                                )
```

I have seen similar issues referring potentially to the DateTime or Boolean fields. However even if I comment them out I get the same result.

### MariaDB:
MariaDB [(none)]> status

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.13-MariaDB, for osx10.15 (x86_64) using readline 5.1

I am using mysqlclient               1.4.6.

Any pointers?
Thanks,
Martin

Comment: `[` is not a valid MySQL character.  Any idea where it is coming from?

Comment: No, which ] are you referring to? My challenge is, this is generated SQL code therefore difficult to locate exact error.

Comment: It is point exactly to `[20]`.  That is in the input.  What is generating the input?

Comment: All the text fields are 100. The rest is decimal or boolean. So, I am kind of guessing it is the DateTimeField. The SQL is generated from Django out of the Python model file. It may be related to the MariaDB version which seems to correspond to MySQL 5.5. But I do not see a way to upgrade as there is no more recent version (at least for MacOS). It works fine with other DBs, but I need MariaDB for the Cloud provider I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django sql produced contains an array. The following model field:

```
alternate_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True,
                            help_text=_('This is a list of alternate grape names'),
                            verbose_name=_('Alternate grape names'),
                            )
```

Resulted in the following sql:

```
`alternate_name` varchar(30)[20] NOT NULL,
```

I have altered the sql removing the array information and run the queries manually.